# Immutability in clojure when incrementing numbers inside my own data structure, going from common lisp mutability to clojure immutability

Tags: clojure, lisp, common-lisp, immutability

I've played around a bit with clojure before doing much more studying of lisp and I want to get back into clojure...

So I have this thing in common lisp:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (x)
        (incf (third (car (member x count-mx
                      :test #'equal
                      :key #'(lambda (x) (list (car x) (cadr x))))))))
    transitions)
```

That for me in clojure translated to (not sure if this is good clojure):

```
(map (fn [x] (swap! (third (some #(if (= x (vec (first %) (second %))) %)
                 count-mx))
            inc))
     transitions)
```

where count-mx, if I used atoms to make the zeroes:

```
[[a a 0] [a b 0] [a c 0] [a d 0] [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 0] [b d 0] [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 0] [d a 0] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]]
```

and transitions:

```
[[a a] [a b] [b c] [c d] [d a] [a b] [b c]]
```

The objective being to increment [a a 0] to [a a 1] after mapping over transitions and seeing [a a]

Although the clojure line does work I cannot use it within a function or let because of immutability, how do I break out of my common lisp thinking? I quite like mapping and modifying values within something, but I'm not sure how to do this efficiently and/or correctly in clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit (Improved answer)

I didn't know: Maps accept also vectors as keys.
In this case, we can directly take the pairs as keys and use `update` in combination with `inc` to update the values (by enhancing the value by 1). I use `sorted-map` because it looks nicer for presentation (sorted) - more performant would be to use `(hash-map)` or `{}` in the `into` expression.

```
(def m (into (sorted-map)        ;; or: `{}` btw `(hash-map)`
             (for [x '[a b c d]  ;; nesting for-loop
                   y '[a b c d]] ;; for sunccinct creation 
               {[x y] 0})))      ;; of all combinations

m 
;; => {[a a] 0, [a b] 0, [a c] 0, [a d] 0, 
;;     [b a] 0, [b b] 0, [b c] 0, [b d] 0, 
;;     [c a] 0, [c b] 0, [c c] 0, [c d] 0, 
;;     [d a] 0, [d b] 0, [d c] 0, [d d] 0}


(def transitions '[[a a] [a b] [b c] [c d] 
                   [d a] [a b] [b c]])

(def m' (reduce (fn [a-map a-transition] 
                  (update a-map a-transition inc))
                m
                transitions))

m'
;; => {[a a] 1, [a b] 2, [a c] 0, [a d] 0, 
;;     [b a] 0, [b b] 0, [b c] 2, [b d] 0, 
;;     [c a] 0, [c b] 0, [c c] 0, [c d] 1, 
;;     [d a] 1, [d b] 0, [d c] 0, [d d] 0}
```

`(reduce (fn [mp key] (update mp key inc)) m '[a b c])` expands to:
`(update (update (update m 'a inc) 'b inc) 'c inc)`
therefore (in an accumulating manner) sequentially updating the values of each key given in `transitions`.

We convert the sorted map into the nested vector form by:

```
(def m'' (into [] (map (comp vec flatten) (seq m'))))

m''
;; => [[a a 1] [a b 2] [a c 0] [a d 0] 
;;     [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 2] [b d 0] 
;;     [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 1] 
;;     [d a 1] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]]
```

We can generalize them to functions:

```
(defn update-map-by-transitions 
  "Update the map `m` successively by transitions"
  [m transitions & {:keys [func] :or {func inc}}]
  (reduce (fn [m' tr] (update m' tr func))
          m
          transitions))

(defn map-to-vecs 
  "Transform transition map to flatten vectors"
  [m & {:keys [vec-func] :or {vec-func flatten}}] 
  (into [] (map (comp vec vec-func) (seq m))))
          
(def m' (update-map-by-transitions m transitions))
(def m'' (map-to-vecs m' :vec-func flatten))

m''
;; [[a a 1] [a b 2] [a c 0] [a d 0] 
;;  [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 2] [b d 0] 
;;  [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 1] 
;;  [d a 1] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]]

;; or do:
(def m''' (map-to-vecs m' :vec-func identity))
m'''
;; [[[a a] 1] [[a b] 2] [[a c] 0] [[a d] 0] 
;;  [[b a] 0] [[b b] 0] [[b c] 2] [[b d] 0] 
;;  [[c a] 0] [[c b] 0] [[c c] 0] [[c d] 1] 
;;  [[d a] 1] [[d b] 0] [[d c] 0] [[d d] 0]]
```

### Original answer

I am also coming from Common Lisp. By the way, you abbreviate it CL or "Lisp". But CLISP actually means one of the many implementations of CL (next to sbcl, abcl, ECL, etc.). So don't call CL clisp ... (to avoid others to be annoyed about it).

I think using nested vectors for this task is tedious and - when scaling up later - less performant.

Instead, prefer maps. They have the function `update` and in case of nested maps `update-in` to manipulate and "mutate" the values of a map which will prove very handy for this task.

To take a vec `[a b c d]` and generate `{a 0 b 0 c 0 d 0}`, I would define:

```
(defn mapper [vec default-val]
  (into {} (for [x vec] {x default-val})))

(mapper '[a b] 0) ;; => {a 0 b 0}
```

Now, we want two keys for storing a count value for them: Nest the maps:

```
(def m (mapper '[a b c d] (mapper '[a b c d] 0)))

m
;; =>{a {a 0, b 0, c 0, d 0}, 
;;    b {a 0, b 0, c 0, d 0}, 
;;    c {a 0, b 0, c 0, d 0}, 
;;    d {a 0, b 0, c 0, d 0}}
```

We can anytime convert them back to your favorized nested vector form (I admit, it is better human readable):

```
(defn nested-maps-to-vecs [nested-map]
  (vector (for [[k v] nested-map
        [ik iv] v]
    [k ik iv])))

(nested-maps-to-vecs m)
;;=> [[a a 0] [a b 0] [a c 0] [a d 0] 
;;    [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 0] [b d 0] 
;;    [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 0] 
;;    [d a 0] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]]
```

Now define `transitions`:

```
(def transitions '[[a a] [a b] [b c] [c d] [d a] [a b] [b c]])
```

Using `inc` function for update and the handy `update-in` we can
"mutate" the values of the map:

```
(def m' (reduce (fn [a-map a-transition] (update-in a-map a-transition inc)) m transitions))

m'
;; => {a {a 1, b 2, c 0, d 0}, 
;;     b {a 0, b 0, c 2, d 0}, 
;;     c {a 0, b 0, c 0, d 1}, 
;;     d {a 1, b 0, c 0, d 0}}

(nested-maps-to-vecs m')
;; => [[a a 1] [a b 2] [a c 0] [a d 0] 
;;     [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 2] [b d 0] 
;;     [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 1] 
;;     [d a 1] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]]
```

Voila!

`(update-in a-map a-transition inc)` gets e.g. `[a b]` and accesses in the nested map with the key sequence `a` and then `b` and takes the value which is in that "place" and applies `inc` to it and "stores" the result into that "place".
Well, it doesn't store it actually, but it returns a new map with the updated value.
This new map is the new `a-map` in the `reduce` function and taking the next `a-transition` this updated map will be further updated.
So `reduce` is the trick to "accumulate" the updates by constant update and capture of the updated map while walking through the `transitions` sequence.

Clojure has a very efficient way to "update" its immutable structures. It saves only the changes while referring to the unchanged rest. Therefore this "generation of a new updated map" by `update` sounds worse than it actually is: It is actually highly efficient performance- as well as memory footprint-wise. This special storing strategy cannot be pursued by Common Lisp and other Lisps or languages, because of mutability. Only pure functional languages with ensured immutability of data like Clojure or Haskell can use this kind of strategy for storing and updating their immutable data.

Clojure has however also mutability in `atom`s which has to be specifically declared to be an `atom`. In this case, to use `atom`s as values in the map or the nested vectors would be not very the Clojure way.

I am also still trying to wrap my head around this all.

Have fun in your journey!

Comment: For the records: `update` and `update-in` also work on (nested) vectors. `(update-in [[[1 2 3]]] [0 0] conj 4)`

Comment: @cfrick thanks! the 'keys' are his case are indexes. And then yes - vectors are kind of maps which have as keys position indexes ... however, when using them, he has to match the values somehow with the transition keys ... so it is still better to use maps.

Comment: Very cool, will be studying this. I was stumped because I can write clojure and it will work in the repl, then get confused when trying to make it a proper function. I find that things I have written in common lisp are much shorter and readable (because I can just put anything in lists and do whatever I want with them) than the sometimes strange and hieroglyphic solutions I find in clojure docs.

Comment: @analogsamurai It is true - CL just feels much more "free". The thing is Clojure enforces a stricter functional programming than CL. Instead of classes, Clojure uses `hash-map`s. There exist a `defstruct` but it is not really used. If you watch youtube videos of Rich Hickey you will learn why (the better write 100 functions for 1 (or few) type(s) than 100 functions for 10 types philosophy). By enforcing immutability (except `atom`s - `atom`s are kind of `setf`-able variables - well coming from CL, I was missing `setf` a lot! :D - but we do `setf` for performance reasons ) Clojure can handle ..

Comment: .. can handle generation of "new" data out of a previous one very efficiently (not everythign gets copied - but only the new part gets generated - and using kind of pointers referred to the unchanged parts). Therefore no need to `setf`. I am also trying to wrap my head around the Clojure way. - which parts did you found especially weird?

Answer (score 4):

Use `frequencies` to count the transitions, then a `for` list comprehension to build the desired result:

```clj
(defn mat [transitions]
  (let [freqs (frequencies transitions)
        verts '[a b c d]]
    (for [x verts
          y verts]
      [x y (get freqs [x y] 0)])))
```

```clj
(def t '[[a a] [a b] [b c] [c d] [d a] [a b] [b c]])

(mat t) ; => ([a a 1] [a b 2] [a c 0] [a d 0]
        ;     [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 2] [b d 0]
        ;     [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 1]
        ;     [d a 1] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0])
```

Comment: I like this because the code is minimal and readable, but the other answer expands much more on immutability related to the post title. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in clojure.

```clj
user> (def count-mx '[[a a 0] [a b 0] [a c 0] [a d 0] [b a 0] [b b 0] [b c 0] [b d 0] [c a 0] [c b 0] [c c 0] [c d 0] [d a 0] [d b 0] [d c 0] [d d 0]])
#'user/count-mx
user> (def transitions '[[a a] [a b] [b c] [c d] [d a] [a b] [b c]])
#'user/transitions
user> (reduce (fn [cmx xtn]
                (mapv (fn [[x1 x2 c :as mx]]
                        (let [x (pop mx)]
                          (if (= x xtn)
                            (conj x (inc c))
                            mx)))
                      cmx))
              count-mx
              transitions)
[[a a 1]
 [a b 2]
 [a c 0]
 [a d 0]
 [b a 0]
 [b b 0]
 [b c 2]
 [b d 0]
 [c a 0]
 [c b 0]
 [c c 0]
 [c d 1]
 [d a 1]
 [d b 0]
 [d c 0]
 [d d 0]]
user>
```

It's better to just think about pure functions and not worry about doing mutation for efficiency.  For example, in this above example, count-mx is still the same original value.

Comment: I like this a lot because it's clean but is a little hard to read for myself. Might get to this level of good clojure eventually

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that the data items being counted are pairs like `[:a :c]`, I would use a pair vector as the map key. Also, in Clojure it is more common to use keywords like `:a` as data tokens rather than symbols like `a`.

First define the tokens, and the pairs of tokens:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def tokens [:a :b :c :d])

(def pairs (vec (for [x tokens
                      y tokens]
                  [x y])))
```

and then initialize a count map with a zero total for each pair:

```
(def counts (into (sorted-map) (zipmap pairs (repeat 0))))

(dotest
  (is= pairs [[:a :a] [:a :b] [:a :c] [:a :d]
              [:b :a] [:b :b] [:b :c] [:b :d]
              [:c :a] [:c :b] [:c :c] [:c :d]
              [:d :a] [:d :b] [:d :c] [:d :d]])
  (is= counts
    {[:a :a] 0, [:a :b] 0, [:a :c] 0, [:a :d] 0,
     [:b :a] 0, [:b :b] 0, [:b :c] 0, [:b :d] 0,
     [:c :a] 0, [:c :b] 0, [:c :c] 0, [:c :d] 0,
     [:d :a] 0, [:d :b] 0, [:d :c] 0, [:d :d] 0}))
```

The unit test shows all is as we desire.

Then a simple accumulator function using `update-in`

```
(defn accumulator
  [data]
  (let [curr-cnt (atom counts)]
    (doseq [item data]
      (swap! curr-cnt update-in [item] inc))
    (deref curr-cnt)))
```

Now, define some sample data and verify the result:

```
(def data [[:a :a] [:a :a] [:a :a] [:a :b] [:b :c] [:c :d] [:d :a] [:a :b] [:b :c]])

(dotest
  (is= (accumulator data)
    {[:a :a] 3,
     [:a :b] 2,
     [:a :c] 0,
     [:a :d] 0,
     [:b :a] 0,
     [:b :b] 0,
     [:b :c] 2,
     [:b :d] 0,
     [:c :a] 0,
     [:c :b] 0,
     [:c :c] 0,
     [:c :d] 1,
     [:d :a] 1,
     [:d :b] 0,
     [:d :c] 0,
     [:d :d] 0}))
```

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).